# LUKS keyfile lost

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

I lost the keyfile to open a LUKS partition.

The command luksDump tell me that there is 2 key slots, so one them is certainly a passphrase that I left after adding the keyfile. Is there a way to know that for sure?

I'm trying to bruteforce with [this program](https://github.com/glv2/bruteforce-luks) and a wordlist of variants of my passwords, but no luck so far.

I also have a backup of the header, can it help ?